# Objective-C - Override URLs in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, overriding

Is it possible to override URLs in a UIWebView?  For instance, if I want to detect tel: links and add the +1 to the beginning of the number if it doesn't have it already.

On Android I do it like this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:1")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                                Uri.parse(url)); 
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {

                    int start = url.indexOf(":");
                    String suffix = url.substring(start + 1);
                    String newUrl = "tel:1" + suffix;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                                Uri.parse(newUrl)); 
                        startActivity(intent); 
                }

                else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return true;
            }
```

How can I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` web view delegate method. Check the type for a "click" and then check the request's URL to see if it is a `tel:` URL. If so, you can process the URL as needed.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        NSString *scheme = [url scheme];
        if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
            // Update the url as needed

            // Now handled the url by asking the app to open it
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            return NO; // don't let the webview process it.
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```